# Name and description are too small on the user profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

When there is a long address, name and description becomes too small on the profile page. Then, it is hard to read. Instead of it, if *Address* would go to two lines if it is too long, it would be good.

> [image]

This can be fixed like in the following screenshot. Credit: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz

[image]

Comment: Yay! Responsiveness bugs. Those are way more fun then Jon Skeets reputation and badges no longer fitting in his usercard.

Comment: One could argue that you'd need a lot less details to get the same address. Or that you're deliberately entering as much as possible to break the UI.

Comment: @Cerbrus There are more longer single words also there for address https://www.worldatlas.com/articles/the-10-longest-place-names-in-the-world.html

Comment: @Cerbrus And if all address less than my address, I think SO should limit the chars of address

Comment: Or we could just accept that the UI reacts like this in exceptional situations.

Comment: Or the address could break to the next line after a maximum amount of characters...

Comment: @IDarkCoder: I assume you meant after a certain width is required. Word wrapping on string length is messy.

Comment: @Cerbrus it's not like this is an unheard of problem that we cannot figure out a solution to, so we may as well leave it to the will of the gods. We do know what the problem is, we have all likely seen it many, many times. There are many known solutions - make the text scroll, break it up, for example. I'm sure if an actual designer (which we know SO employs) sits down, they can come up with more and more elegant solutions. Failing that, they can just post a question on SO or UX and would get many good answers.

Comment: @Cerbrus Good point, probably a better approach.

Comment: @VLAZ: I think you're over-analyzing my comment.

Comment: I spent literally seconds on [this](https://i.imgur.com/pmVqmpA.png) it's a `max-width: 266px`

Comment: @VLAZ: Have I said anything about the complexity of this issue, any where?

Comment: @Cerbrus you suggested leaving the bug as it is, instead of fixing it. Whether due to complexity or what, I don't know but I still don't understand why not just fix it.

Comment: @VLAZ: Okay, so don't lecture me about how simple it is. My reasoning here is that this bug report is quite a corner case, which doesn't seem like a realistic scenario. This is not the first time this OP submitted bug reports like that.

Comment: @Cerbrus Bug is a bug. It does matter if there is a rule in SO something like "Don't start meta question for small bugs". Sure, then I will not post small bugs.

Comment: _"One could argue that <...> you're deliberately entering as much as possible to break the UI."_

Comment: @Cerbrus I am reminded at how many packages I couldn't get delivered at home because of such a "corner case". At least once I couldn't even *order* at all. Another one I (almost) never received because when it was printed, the long line was cut off. Sure, this isn't a site that does deliveries but the design is still wrong. Leaving it wrong knowingly when the fix does not require a lot of resources, seems...bizarre. We've now spent more time that what SE would probably need to fix it.

Comment: @Cerbrus `One could argue that <...> you're deliberately entering as much as possible to break the UI.`  I didn't do it. Even I do it, what is wrong about it? It is a help for SO team to identify bugs.

Comment: Deliberately breaking the UI isn't exactly a "bug". It's like putting the wrong fuel into a car to see if it'll run, and then complaining that the car didn't spit the fuel back out. @Vlaz, you don't need to convince me this is simple to fix. And you can't convince me that this is a valid scenario. I just voiced my opinion, and that's that. This isn't a debate.

Comment: @Cerbrus Still, if the car company and build the car with good quality which doesn't break some parts of the car even mistakenly putting wrong fuel is good. If we mistakenly put wrong fuel and it breaks the car, then car company need to try to correct it.,

Comment: No, if you put the wrong furl into a car, then it’s your own problem. There isn’t a car brand that will pay for the repairs.

Comment: While in principle I side with _"not something we should care about_", this is easily fixable by either restricting input to a max length or a tiny change in the CSS. Still, "breaking" HTML rendering when you have to render user input is an all too common scenario. As long as it only breaks on unreasonable corner cases, and it is not a security concern, wouldn't invest time on this.

Comment: Cross meta dupe (since Nov 2018): https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318125/241919

Comment: @YvetteColomb And you're going to tell that to all [these](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1074078/top-100-highest-profile-views) people?

Comment: @NickA: boy, you found a motherload of defanged spam accounts with that query.. Nothing lost there!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Honestly, I'm not even remotely surprised by that..., but an official response would be nice on this (most responses for users >3k are jokes or just long names, except the occasional university), or at least a GUI update to make it clear

Comment: I hope none of you "we don't need to bother with corner cases" programmers end up working with me. It's a bug. Put it in the list. If it's low priority, fine, but don't argue that's "not a bug".

Comment: I am tempted to introduce a [meta-tag:bucket-of-paint] tag for things which pertain to the bikeshed at this point.

Comment: I am tempted to move to [Taumatawhakatangi­hangakoauauotamatea­turipukakapikimaunga­horonukupokaiwhen­uakitanatahu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taumatawhakatangihangakoauauotamateaturipukakapikimaungahoronukupokaiwhenuakitanatahu)

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm tempted to move to "Krungthepmahanakhon Amonrattanakosin Mahintharayutthaya Mahadilokphop Noppharatratchathaniburirom Udomratchaniwetmahasathan Amonphimanawatansathit Sakkathattiyawitsanukamprasit" (aka Bangkok)

Comment: @VFDan Yeah, but that has spaces in it, which allows it to be wrapped :)

Comment: @DavidPostill Well, in the first screenshot, the name has spaces, but isn't wrapped :)

Answer (score 7):

Fixed at last:

[image: screenshot of the profile from the report, now constrained]

Slightly more space than normal *will* be allowed for the stats column in cases where a field has... this much content... But only to a point; after about 316 pixels, it should not get any wider. Text will overflow off the page if need-be rather than forcing the central bio column to collapse.